# How can I configure Chrome so that it doesn't block BlueJeans Event videos?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, video, bluejeans

I am attending a BlueJeans Event and I see the message:

> Browser's autoplay policy is blocking BlueJeans Event videos.

[image]

(in case anyone is concerned about privacy, the image is [publicly accessible](https://web.archive.org/web/20230627154820/https://blog.adobe.com/en/publish/2020/04/14/mira-dontcheva))

How can I configure Chrome so that it doesn't block BlueJeans Event videos?

Comment: (1) When the video is playing, do you see a small switch at the bottom of the video that allows autoplay? (2) Try invoking Chrome with the parameter `--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required`.

Comment: @harrymc thanks! 1) I didn't see any 2) sounds good I'll try next time I have BlueJeans Event.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has been moving away from allowing autoplay of any kind, and
successive version have been laying down strict rules.

I have listed below one solution, but note that successive versions
of Chrome might invalidate it.

**Disable autoplay policy**

This is done by running Chrome with the following parameter:

```
chrome.exe --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required
```

You might need to specify the full path for `chrome.exe`.

If this works, note that this will enable autoplay on *all websites*.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try an extension like [AutoplayStopper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoplaystopper/ejddcgojdblidajhngkogefpkknnebdh). In its menu, it has an option to enable autoplay for a website. It worked for me to get autoplay working on a different website, not sure if it'll do anything here, but worth trying as that's more comfortable than relaunching Chrome with a specific flag.